# Expo Interactive Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to send interactive push notifications with [Expo](https://expo.io). I can send normal push notifications fine, and I can even send *local* interactive push notifications, however I cannot send remote interactive push notifications

According to [this section](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notification-categories) of the docs, you create a category, which I do:

```
Notifications.createCategoryAsync('daily_question', [
    {
        actionId: 'yes',
        buttonTitle: 'Yes',
    },
    {
        actionId: 'no',
        buttonTitle: 'No',
    },
]);
```

The working *local* notification then sends (with the interactive buttons) like this:

```
Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({
    title: '...',
    body: '...',
    data: {...},
    categoryId: 'daily_question',
});
```

Is there a way to either:

1. Send a remote interactive push notification as specified in [this section](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/#message-format) of the docs with the `_category` key
2. Send a "background" push notification and have a background task send a local interactive push notification

Comment: Same issue on Android. have you managed to work around this?

Comment: @Enijar Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@nathanziarek/interactive-notifications), I tried it on iOs and when I click (long enough) on the notifications, it shows custom action (button One, button two, three),

Comment: I see now that the buttons show on iOS with a long press, but on Android the buttons do not show – see here https://i.imgur.com/xj66DyZ.png

Answer (score 1):

I got remote interactive push notifications working by sending the category id with the key `categoryId`.